# R how to choose rows with values in two columns the same?

Tags: r

An example:

```
> df1
  c1 c2 c3
1  2  3  8
2  1  6  2
3  2  9  8
```

I want to get a subset where c1 and c3 values are the same, so in this example I would like the result to be:

```
  c1 c2 c3
1  2  3  8
3  2  9  8
```

Is there any straightforward way to do this in R? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can apply `duplicated` on the subset of dataset with the columns of interest to find the rows that are all duplicates and use that to subset the rows

```
df1[duplicated(df1[c('c1','c3')])|duplicated(df1[c('c1','c3')], fromLast=TRUE),]
#  c1 c2 c3
#1  2  3  8
#3  2  9  8
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this and it works. I don't quite understand how the '|' works in this context, but I also tried to add another column c4 and this sentence seem to work as well.